# remove an array from AOA perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I have an array of array that looks like this -

```
$VAR1 = [
          'sid_R.ba',
          'PS20TGB2YM13',
          'SID_r.BA',
          'ARS',
          'XBUE'
        ]; $VAR2 = [
          'sddff.pk',
          'PQ10XD06K800',
          'SDDFF.PK',
          'USD',
          'PINX'
        ]; $VAR3 = [
          'NULL',
          'NULL',
          'NULL',
          '.',
          'XNAS'
        ]; $VAR4 = [
          'NULL',
          'NULL',
          'NULL',
          '.',
          'XNAS'
        ]; $VAR5 = [
          'NULL',
          'NULL',
          'NULL',
          'EUR',
          'OTCX'
        ]; $VAR6 = [
          'sid.ba',
          'PS20TGB1TN17',
          'SID.BA',
          'ARS',
          'XBUE'
        ];
```

I want to remove the complete block (array ref) if any of its element is NULL

I have a code in which the array gets generated, so I tried a for loop to delete but then the index of the array is reduced on the inside the for loop.

So I dont know in which order the array will be or the length of array.
Please I need a generic solution.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to have an array like

```
my @AoA = (
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, "NULL"],
  [9, 10],
);
```

You want to select all child arrays that do not contain `"NULL"`. Easy: Just use nested `grep`:

```
my @AoA_sans_NULL = grep {
  not grep { $_ eq "NULL" } @$_
} @AoA;
```

The `grep { CONDITION } @array` selects all elements from `@array` where the `CONDITION` evaluates to true.

The `grep { $_ eq "NULL" } @$_` counts the number of `"NULL"`s in the inner array. If this is zero, our condition is true, else, we don't want to keep that sub-array.

Comment: We came up with essentially the same solution, although you've done a much better job of unpacking it and explaining it.

Answer (score 5):

```
    use List::MoreUtils qw(none);
    my @filtered = grep {
      none { $_ eq "NULL" } @$_;
    } @array;
```

Comment: Your `not any ...` could be written `none { $_ eq "NULL" } @$_`

Comment: This is now the (IMHO) most perlish, and probably most efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
my @new_array = grep { scalar(grep { $_ eq 'NULL' } @{$_}) == 0 } @old_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Old school:

```
my @filtered = ();

ARRAY_LOOP:
for my $array ( @AoA ){

  ITEM_LOOP:
  for my $item ( @$array ){

    next ARRAY_LOOP if $item eq 'NULL';

  } # end ITEM_LOOP

  push @filtered, $array;

} # end ARRAY_LOOP
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will be slower than the others, but an in-place solution might be useful if the data-set is very large.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(any);
for(my $i = 0; $i < @AoA; $i ++) {
    splice @AoA, $i --, 1
        if any { $_ eq "NULL" } @{ $AoA[$i] };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-`grep` of a `grep` solution:

```
my @array = ...;  #Array of Arrays
for my $array_index ( reverse 0 .. $#array ) { 
    my @inner_array = @{ $array[$array_index] };
    if ( grep /^NULL$/, @inner_array ) {
        splice @array, $array_index, 1;
    }
}
say Dumper @array;
```

The `splice` command removes the entire subarray. I don't need to create `@inner_array` I could have used my dereferenced `@{ $array[$array_index] }` in the if statement, but I like going for clarity.

The only gotcha is that you have to go through your array of array backwards. If you go through your array from first element to last element, you'll remove element 2 which causes all the other elements to have their indexes decremented. If I first remove element 4, element 0 to 3 don't change their index.

It's not as *elegant* as the `grep` of a `grep` solutions, but it's a lot easier to maintain. Imagine someone who has to go through your program six months from now trying to figure out what:

```
grep { not grep { $_ eq "NULL" } @$_ } @array;
```

is doing.